# How to access nested object array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer. 
I just want to know how to access the values in `service_name array` in a `console.log`

Below is the array and just a snip out of the data.

```js
var a = [{"ID":102254,"Name":"obj 1","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":226619,"Name":"DIDE","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":224522,"Name":"CAT","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":122533,"Name":"Mirror","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]}]


console.log(JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4))
```

Comment: Well, you have an array of objects, each object containing a `service_name` array. Do you just want a single one, or do you want an array of the arrays, etc.? What would your desired final result look like?

Comment: I will be filtering down the above array to just one ID. and then will want to access just the service_name info for that ID

Comment: Answer posted. Let me know if that's what you were looking for

Comment: Just marked, an answer, thanks for all the responses, they all do what I was looking for, but the one I marked suits my needs best. 
Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access it like an array, this is how you would access the service_name values in the 4th item in the array

```js
var a = [{"ID":102254,"Name":"obj 1","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":226619,"Name":"DIDE","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":224522,"Name":"CAT","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":122533,"Name":"Mirror","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]}]


console.log(JSON.stringify(a[3].service_name[0]))
console.log(JSON.stringify(a[3].service_name[1]))
```

Comment: This does exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```js
var a = [{"ID":102254,"Name":"obj 1","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":226619,"Name":"DIDE","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":224522,"Name":"CAT","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":122533,"Name":"Mirror","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]}]
a.forEach((e)=>console.log(e.service_name));
```

if you need a result array:

```js
var a = [{"ID":102254,"Name":"obj 1","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":226619,"Name":"DIDE","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":224522,"Name":"CAT","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":122533,"Name":"Mirror","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]}]
var res = a.map((e)=>e.service_name);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [{"ID":102254,"Name":"obj 1","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":226619,"Name":"DIDE","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":224522,"Name":"CAT","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":122533,"Name":"Mirror","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]}]

a.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.service_name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to return the service names array of the element whose ID matches the id you are looking for like so:

```js
function getServiceNamesById (data, id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].ID === id) {
      return data[i].service_name;
    }
  }
  return [];
}

var a = [{"ID":102254,"Name":"obj 1","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":226619,"Name":"DIDE","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":224522,"Name":"CAT","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":122533,"Name":"Mirror","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]}];

var id = 226619;

console.log(getServiceNamesById(a, id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  :

```
  var a = [{"ID":102254,"Name":"obj 1","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":226619,"Name":"DIDE","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":224522,"Name":"CAT","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]},{"ID":122533,"Name":"Mirror","service_name":["Open  Ticket","Escalation Ticket"]}]

 a.forEach(function(item){ // item is an object
     item.service_name.forEach(function(service){ //item.service_name is  an array
     console.log(service);
     });
 });
```

Good luck